# Can I choose specific nodes to show in a view?

Tags: views, 9

I have a Drupal 9 site with a view that shows products, but I do not want to show all products, I only want to show a select few of them.

Is it possible to filter like this? Instead of showing all the products?

Ideally I'd like a UI where I can manage the products manually. E.g. if I have 5 products but only want to display Product 1 and Product 4, I can select those 2 products.

Comment: You should be able to create an entity queue (https://www.drupal.org/project/entityqueue), and filter the results by that queue. I haven't done it since D7 with the Node queue module, but this module appears to be the successor, so you should be able to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to manage the products manually, i.e. not base the filter on a product field value, the [Entityqueue](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityqueue) module offers an easy solution.

1. Install the module if you don't already have it
2. Create a queue for the products at /admin/structure/entityqueue/add
3. Choose the appropriate entity type and bundle under *Entity settings*
4. Save and add some products to it
5. In your View, add a relationship to the entityqueue

Once you've done that, only the products in the queue will be in the View's results.

As a bonus, you can also control the sort order with the entity queue if needed. Just add a sort criteria for *Content Queue Position* to the View.